# Why sum() function isn't giving the exact value in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

[image: table elaborate_term_result_sheet]

```
select s_id, s_f_name, s_l_name, s_roll_no, s_class, 
       SUM(mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 as mid_english, 
       SUM(mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 as mid_mathematics,
       semester_final_english,
       semester_final_mathematics,
       SUM((mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 + semester_final_english) as total_english, 
       SUM((mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 + semester_final_mathematics) as total_mathematics,
       SUM((mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 + (mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 + semester_final_mathematics + semester_final_mathematics) as total
from elaborate_term_result_sheet 
group by s_f_name, s_l_name
order by s_roll_no;
```

After running this query created, it does show the out put, but value is getting a bit fluctuated

[image: Result of the query]

mid_1_english + mid_2_english = mid_english

mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics = mid_mathematics

mid_english + semester_final_english = total_english

mid_mathematics + semester_final_mathematics = total_mathematics

total = total_english + total_mathematics

Comment: Maybe you can change for example SUM()/2 as follows (1.0 * SUM())/2  This will change the data type used from integer to decimal so you will not lose decimal data in calculations

Comment: Nope, It doesn't work

Comment: What value is wrong?

Comment: 168.50 is supposed to be the total for the 1st tuple

Comment: `... + semester_final_mathematics + semester_final_mathematics) as total` -- can you spot any (logic) error in this fragment of code?

Comment: Cast the operations: `cast(SUM(mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics) as float) /2`

Comment: Are you sure your last calculation should be semester_final_mathematics+semester_final_mathematics? Should it be Maths + English?

Comment: If your `total` is supposed to be `total_english` + `total_mathematics`, then your code for `total` has a typo - it includes `semester_final_mathematics` twice, but omits `semester_final_english`. This also exactly explains the difference in total from 176.5 to the expected 168.5 in the first line (re, comment above). You almost certainly mistyped this. Flagged as typo, please close.

Comment: Hi. You give neither an example nor specification of what output you want--how do you expect us to know what a correct query is? "isn't giving the exact value", "is getting a bit fluctuated" & "It doesn't work" say nothing. Make the effort to clearly say what you mean. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify via post edits, not via comments.

Comment: Snapshots of table and the query output are given, do go through those

Comment: the whole table and query output result are given, why can't these help as examples? would you be more specific about the kind of example or specification that you are expecting

Comment: go through the example please and then only you would realize why I said "is getting a bit fluctuated".

Answer (score 0):

```
select s_id, s_f_name, s_l_name, s_roll_no, s_class, 
   SUM(mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 as mid_english, 
   SUM(mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 as mid_mathematics,
   semester_final_english,
   semester_final_mathematics,
   SUM((mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 + semester_final_english) as total_english, 
   SUM((mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 + semester_final_mathematics) as total_mathematics,
   SUM((mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 + semester_final_english + (mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 + semester_final_mathematics) as total from result_sheet_1 group by s_f_name, s_l_name order by s_roll_no;
```

the only change that gave the right output is

```
SUM((mid_1_english + mid_2_english)/2 + semester_final_english + (mid_1_mathematics + mid_2_mathematics)/2 + semester_final_mathematics) as total
```

[the snapshot of the output of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxvy3.png)